# Request to Steam API working with curl, does not work in browser, insomnia nor flask

Tags: api, flask, steam

I am trying to do a simple GET request to the Steam API:

If I do in the terminal:

```
curl http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/\?key\=XXXXXX\&steamids\=76561197960435530
```

It works:

```
{"response":{"players":[{"steamid":"76561197960435530","communityvisibilitystate":3,"profilestate":1,"personaname":"Robin","profileurl":"https://steamcommunity.com/id/robinwalker/","avatar":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4.jpg","avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_medium.jpg","avatarfull":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/f1/f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4_full.jpg","avatarhash":"f1dd60a188883caf82d0cbfccfe6aba0af1732d4","personastate":0,"realname":"Robin Walker","primaryclanid":"103582791429521412","timecreated":1063407589,"personastateflags":0,"loccountrycode":"US","locstatecode":"WA","loccityid":3961}]}}
```

However, when I type in my local browser the url, I get 404 Bad Request: "Required parameter 'key' is missing".

I though it might be related with CORS, so I tried to sent the response from a local flask application:

```
import requests
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@cross_origin()
def get_data():
    return(requests.get('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/\?key\=XXXXXXX\&steamids\=76561197960435530').content)
```

But I also get 404 Not Found error

Answer (score 0):

When you're making the request via Flask or typing it in your browser, do not escape the url yourself (if you look at the url, you will see stuff like `\?` and `\=`

Use the full url i.e.

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=XXXXXXX&steamids=76561197960435530
```